# btrfs scrub status no_csum

Tags: btrfs

I used two disks to create a btrfs raid 1 mirror, and after adding a bunch of files I ran a scrub.  The command `btrfs scrub status <dir>` reports that it finished with 0 errors.  However, `btrfs scrub status -R <dir>` displays:

```
data_extents_scrubbed: 13887259
tree_extents_scrubbed: 61886
data_bytes_scrubbed: 906996514816
tree_bytes_scrubbed: 1013940224
read_errors: 0
csum_errors: 0
verify_errors: 0
no_csum: 54400
csum_discards: 0
super_errors: 0
malloc_errors: 0
uncorrectable_errors: 0
unverified_errors: 0
corrected_errors: 0
last_physical: 912854614016
```

Particularly, the `no_csum` value looks a bit concerning.  Would this cause a problem if btrfs ever needed to repair any data, or is this fine and expected?

Comment: In my case it was `no_csum: 4179778` in a RAID1 with 878.33GiB of data. Also wondering if I should be worried.

Comment: Here is a discussion which tries to explain this: https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-btrfs/msg31952.html
seems to be related to the free space cache, which is not checksummed since it can be recovered if it gets corrupted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`no_csum`, or absence of checksum means number of files where checksum calculation cannot be applied. Checksums calculation can be disabled for files, directories or partitions using attributes `nodatasum` or [`nodatacow`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/FAQ#Can_I_have_nodatacow_.28or_chattr_.2BC.29_but_still_have_checksumming.3F).

Additionally, it is worth to take a look at the [discussion](https://linux-btrfs.vger.kernel.narkive.com/UHEOkjCw/meaning-of-no-csum-field-when-scrubbing-with-r-option) in BTRFS mailing list which @SIGSEGV has mentioned in the comments. BTRFS uses [free space cache](https://superuser.com/questions/855506/what-is-btrfss-disk-space-caching), which is `nodatacow` by design and it is counted by `btrfs scrub` command.